# How to set Wacom tablet button to secondary click?

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

In Ubuntu settings - Wacom tablet - Map Buttons - Click right button - there is no way to set the button to secondary click on my mouse. There's only useless stuff like 'show onscreen help'.

I need to be able to set the button to secondary click to trigger lots of things in applications without having to switch to the mouse. How please?

Comment: Just press the top button on your pen for right click (lower button for middle click, and the sharp tip for left click). The pad seems to behave somewhat like a keyboard. Reset everything in wacom tablet settings to default

Comment: I don't use the pen buttons because I keep pressing them accidentally and find it much more awkward than using the tablet.